# How do I update MongoDB document fields only if they exist?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider a document like this:

```
{
  "_id": "PmjoDDjKPHZSKzbGB",
  "name": "Foo",
  "parent": null,
}
```

I want to update some of those fields with this object:

```
data = {
  "name": "Bar",
  "nonExistingField": "moon",
  "otherNonExistingField": "sun"
}
```

How can I use `update()` and the `data` object to update the Mongo document **without inserting** `nonExistingField` and `otherNonExistingField`?

Comment: Should the documents be updated at all if those fields don't exist?

Comment: The update won't do anything then. So I don't really care.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update(
{"_id": "PmjoDDjKPHZSKzbGB","fieldToBeUpdated":{$exists:true}},
{$set: {"fieldToBeUpdated":date}
);
```

The filter document checks for equality condition corresponding to _id. In addition, it only picks up the document if the 'fieldToBeUpdated' exists.

The update document equates the field to the declared JSON object.